# 'Binding color property to border background using datatrigger'

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am new to WPF technology and I am using MVVM architecture. I want my border to change color when property bound in ViewModel changes its value. lets look at the code :

In my XAML :

```
<Window.Resources>
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}" x:Key="LineColor">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding lcolor}" Value="Blue">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green">

                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

I am binding it to my border :

```
<Border CornerRadius="1,1,0,0" Style="{StaticResource LineColor}" >
```

Then In my ViewModel I took simple string :

```
public string lcolor="Blue";
```

But its not working at all. Please help me out.

**EDIT**:  I tried it as follows:

```
public Boolean lcolor
    {
            get { return (Boolean)this.GetValue(StateProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(StateProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "lcolor", typeof(Boolean), typeof(CallControlViewModel));
```

But it's giving me the following error :

> Error 9
>
> "PSWGS.Client.Module.CallControl.ViewModels.CallControlViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'GetValue' and no extension method 'GetValue' accepting a first argument of type 'PSWGS.Client.Module.CallControl.ViewModels.CallControlViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [data binding overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and [about debugging bindings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx), once you understood everything you may come back.

`lcolor` is a [field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx), it needs to be a [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), further you might want to have a look at [`INPC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).

Comment: You did not mention any in your question, what error is it then?

Comment: Error9 "PSWGS.Client.Module.CallControl.ViewModels.CallControlViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'GetValue' and no extension method 'GetValue' accepting a first argument of type 'PSWGS.Client.Module.CallControl.ViewModels.CallControlViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)     C:\P1NG911\Product\CAD\Development\Client\Software\Build\CallControlModule\ViewModels\CallControlViewModel.cs   68  40  PSWGS.Client.Module.CallControl

Comment: @deathrace.dj: please do **NOT** edit someone else's answer to add further information.  You should edit your own question instead.

Comment: @deathrace.dj: What you did there is a [dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx), which you *do not want* in a ViewModel, also DPs can only be declared on dependency objects. Again, read the links and come back when you think you understood them and [implement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) [INPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).

Comment: Thanks all. 
I got the solution. actually my border's parent grid bound to the object of a class in the viewmodel. so used the same class's property.
@Luke Woodward, am really sorry, I recently started using this blog. so I didn't know how to extend my question. It wont happen again.